# Able to cast the ArrayList<Set<String>> to ArrayList<String> String without class cast exception

Tags: java, casting

I am doing following operations.

```
    Set<Set<String>> set1 = new HashSet<Set<String>>();
    Set<Set<String>> set2 = new HashSet<Set<String>>();

    set1.add(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("s1","s2")));
    set1.add(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("s4","s5")));

    set2.add(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("s5","s4")));


    ArrayList<String> ob = (ArrayList<String>)CollectionUtils.subtract(set1, set2);
    ArrayList<Set<String>> ob1 = (ArrayList<Set<String>>)CollectionUtils.subtract(set1, set2);
    System.out.println(ob);
    System.out.println(ob1);
```

It is giving following output.
[[s2, s1]] 
[[s2, s1]]

Shouldn't it give the class cast exception in first case?

Thanks,
Shantanu

Comment: Your compiler should be giving you a warning that this is an unchecked cast (i.e., a cast that can't be enforced at runtime, and can therefore result in a later `ClassCastException` somewhere where there's no explicit cast). Either way, you can find lots of information (including lots of Stack Overflow questions) by [Googling `unchecked cast`](https://www.google.com/search?q=unchecked+cast).

Comment: Hi Ruakh,It is giving me the same warning in both cases.

Comment: So, you should have Googled the warning-message. Or, at the *very* least, you should have included the warning-message in your question here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics is compile time feature of java language so in your code at run time what you are doing is casting it to `ArrayList` so eventually it is an `ArrayList` so no execption.

Also your code does not do anything with returned 'ArrayList' it just prints it which calls `toString()` method so your code has currently no possiblity to have `ClassCastExpection`

Comment: Agree but at run time also it is ArrayList<Set<String>> not ArrayList<
String>

Comment: @shantanu: no, at runtime it is just an arraylist.

Comment: @shantanu At runtime its only `ArrayList` there is nothing called as  `ArrayList<Set<String>>` now if you are talking about contents of the list then it will cause you problem when you try to cast elements inside the `ArrayList`

Answer (score 0):

The type arguments that you supply for `ob1` and `ob2` are not present at runtime.  The `println` method does not carry about the actual types since it is just calling the `Object#toString` method.  You would not get a `ClassCastException` unless you tried to use the objects stored in the array lists directly as the incorrect type.

For example, you would get an exception if you did the following.

```
String s = ob.iterator.next();
```